# To specify column names, why same parameter name is used in `pd.read_csv` and `pd.DataFrame`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While working with pandas, I have encountered that the two most common ways of creating a new `data-Frame` using **pandas** are as follows;

**1.** **pandas.read_csv()** `Type: < class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' >`

**2.** **pandas.DataFrame()** `Type: < class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' >`

Both use different parameters for taking a `list` of *column names* as input.

---

### Syntax:

- For **pd.read_csv** is as given;

  ```
  pandas.read_csv(filepath, sep=',', delimiter=None, header='infer', names=None)
  ```
- For **pd.DataFrame** is as given;

  ```
  pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None)
  ```

Should I prefer with changing the parameter `"names"` to `"columns"` in `pandas.read_csv()`. Does it make any sense?

---

After that again, while saving `data-frames` into a *CSV-file* using `df.to_csv`, we use the parameter name `columns` as given.

```
df.to_csv(self, path_or_buf=None, sep=', ', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None)
```

Can above-given techniques change to `columns` in python?

Comment: Are you asking about changing the source code? To me this seems like a question for pandas GitHub project page, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There has been some [discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29771) on such inconsistencies in pandas. It seems like the proposed changes are in line with what you suggested. Nonetheless, developers have not arrived at a conclusion yet. Thus, as of now, you might not use the parameter `columns` as an alias for `names` in `pd.read_csv` method.

If you tried passing `columns` as a parameter you will encounter the following error:

```
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

Fortunately, you may use a decorator to achieve what you need:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import wraps

def enable_columns_parameter(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'columns' in kwargs:
            kwargs['names'] = kwargs.pop('columns')
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

pd.read_csv = enable_columns_parameter(pd.read_csv)
```

After applying the decorator to the `pd.read_csv` function, this line would work fine without any errors:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', columns=['any', 'given', 'name'])
```